# Parsing Gson with Json not working for Android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, gson

I have a web service class that successfully pulls my JSON from a feed into a `String`.  I want to use Gson to parse it into a `List` of a custom class, but the parsing messes up somehow.

Right now the code that does the parsing looks like this:
http://pastie.org/2079115.
The JSON is included.

I believe the issue occurs because of that extra layer of

```
"article": { ... }, "article": { ... } ...
```

Pretty much everything I can find online tells me to do it like the above, including the Gson API.

The issue is that the articles variable ends up as a list with the correct number of Articles, but all of the data in each Article is null.  I've toyed with the structure of

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Article>>(){}.getType;
```

but any changes just ends up in the articles variable being null and not even holding null Articles.  Any idea where to go from here?

For reference, my Article.java looks like this:
http://pastie.org/2079165

Comment: Have you thought of trying a different library like Jackson?

Comment: Changing to Jackson would not benefit this issue.  Jackson does not currently have a feature to auto-unwrap objects, and any data-binding solutions with Jackson would be mostly identical to similar data-binding solutions with Gson.

Comment: I really wish frameworks did not add these (generally useless) layers of extra wrapping -- they seem to be nr 1 source of confusion for developers. And whether libs should support such wrapping is a double-edged sword: more support there is, more this "feature" gets used...

Comment: At the end of the day I guess the most important thing is to give developers the tools to compensate. In this instance I'm porting over an iPhone app that uses Objective Resource, which works like a charm, and is well documented for edge cases. It seems like both Droid dev and Gson are sparse when it comes to documentation and examples, making it harder to compensate for these things. This is my first Android app and the learning curve has been sharp. Hopefully these tools will become more well-rounded as the Android community matures and gains dominance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that JSON structure does not match the Java structure attempting to be deserialized into, and no custom deserialization processing to handle the mismatch is provided.  So, yes, "the issue occurs because of that extra layer".

A simple solution would be to change the Java structure to match the JSON structure.  The JSON structure is

```
an array of 
    an unnamed object with 
        one element named article with value of
            an object with 
                seven elements named author_id, body, catagory, created_at, id, published, updated_at
```

Here is such an example, using the same JSON as in the original question.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class Foo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArticleContainer>>() {}.getType();
    ArrayList<ArticleContainer> articles = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("input.json"), collectionType);
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(articles));
  }
}

class ArticleContainer
{
  Article article;
}

class Article
{
  public int author_id;
  public String body;
  public String catagory;
  public String created_at;
  public int id;
  public String published;
  public String updated_at;
}
```

Comment: That was exactly the tweak I needed. Thanks a million!

Comment: I#m sorry, i dont understand how to use this.... I'm parsing something similar which explained in hour example... the problem i cant parse is: "classification":"ab 0",
"genres":"Drama",
"trailer":
 {"de":
 [{"id":"11471452",
 "name":"Trailer 1",
 "hq":false}],
"ov":[]},
"trailer_url":"xxx",
... beginning with trailer.. its just one entry there, everything else works...

Comment: @cV2 -- If you have a question, I suggest creating a new post.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response... the format in comments is really bad :) so thanks for your advice, for now i have found a workaround. but i think i've found this problem a few times on the web, but wasnt able to understand the solution. thanks for your reply :)